# Pandas create column for mean of grouped count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped dataframe that looks as follows:

```
 player_id  shot_type  count
    01         03        3
    02         01        3
               03        2
    03         01        4
```

I want to add an additional column which is the mean of the shot_type counts by player_id which would look as follows:

```
 player_id  shot_type  count  mean_shot_type_count_player
    01         03        3            (3+2)/2
    02         01        3            (3+4)/2
               03        2            (3+2)/2
    03         01        4            (3+4)/2
```

Comment: df.groupby('shot')['count'].transform('mean')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GroupBy.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['mean_shot_type_count_player']=df.groupby('shot_type')['count'].transform('mean')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   player_id  shot_type  count  mean_shot_type_count_player
0         01         03      3                          2.5
1         02         01      3                          3.5
2                    03      2                          2.5
3         03         01      4                          3.5
```